# Top view disappeared in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I am adding list of table layouts to a LinearLayout dynamically. For that I used ScrollView to see the list of tables which are added to linear layout.

below is my xml code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RET MASTER SITE REPORTS"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Source code:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (isColorChange) {
            displayDeviceDetails(getColor(R.color.blue), getColor(R.color.lightBlue));
        } else {
            displayDeviceDetails(getColor(R.color.orange), getColor(R.color.lightOrange));
        }
}



 //Method which i am calling from loop
 private void displayDeviceDetails(int titleColor, int cellColor) {
    TableRow row = null;
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_views, null);
        row.setBackgroundColor(titleColor);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle);
        TextView tvText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvRowText);
        if (i == 0) {
            tvText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tvTitle.setText(arr[i]);
        } else {
            changeBgColor(cellColor);
            setBgColor(tvTitle);
            setBgColor(tvText);
            tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tvTitle.setText(arr[i]);
            tvText.setText(arr1[i]);
            row.setBackgroundColor(titleColor);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(row);
    }
    layout.addView(tableLayout);

}
```

In the above code, There is TextView at top of the screen which is used to display some text. I added 3 tables to a linear layout it's showing 1st table from middle followed by next 2 tables with some white space/empty screen at bottom. If I increase number of tables that bottom screen empty space is increasing.

Example: There are 5 tables in a ScrollView, but it will display from 2nd table that might be from table starting or might be from middle of the table, followed by 3rd, 4th n 5th tables with empty space at bottom of the ScrollView.

I can able to see the Text, but I added 5 tables to linear layout inside ScrollView, when I executed that, it will display from 2nd table that might be from table starting or might be from middle, followed by 3rd, 4th n 5th tables with empty space. I have attachment my screen-shots.

Please help me.

[image: Top view of the screen]

[image: Bottom view of the screen]

Comment: there might be problem when you are inserting that table

Comment: I have added my source code. Once check that. The problem is with scroll view only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it ! It's the `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`  in the `LinearLayout` that is the culprit..
Just delete this and everything should be fine.

Comment: But i really shocked, how will that effect to scroll view??

Comment: yes i was also shocked when i come to know this, but this is fact!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the root LinearLayout to RelativeLayout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RET MASTER SITE REPORTS"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: No effect. That is not problem with Root layout.

Comment: I have tried that, but no effect. Anyway Ravi answers is correct. Thank you for your response.