# Can't correct add child to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, addchild

I've a simple task - add child views to a LinearLayout dynamically, but I don't know, how to do it in a proper way.

There are two ways:

**1. Inflate view and passed parent container to the inflate method.**

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item, container, true);
```

At this case, when I've more than one child, LayoutInfater returns the same child view object every time, when inflate it. So I can proper initialized other child views.

**2. The next way is to use LinearLayout method addView(View view).**

The problem is, that the child view lose it's LayoutParams state.
And I must set new LayoutParams for child programmatically. It's a not good practice.

Also we can put child in the complimentary wrapper layout in his own layout resource file. But it's also a not good practice put layout to the wrapper.

My child resource:

```
<RelativeLayout android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height">

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_name"
          android:text="Name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

So what is the proper way to add child to LinearLayout, without adding LayoutParams programmatically and without wrapper layout?

Thank's a lot for help!

Comment: You can check the question. Question has linear layout as a parent and adding tableLayout as a child views.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847066/top-view-disappeared-in-scrollview

Comment: At this sample, root child layout hasn't custom layout params. (such as fixed layout_width or layout_height)

Comment: Do you want to fix the child view width and height?? or you don't want to fix it? Linear layout is root layout and thatz not custom.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-a-layout

Comment: When your child's root layout has, for example, layout_height="50dp", so when yout add this child to container, such as container.addView(child), child's layout_height set as wrap_content, because it is LayoutParams parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way?

```
View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);

parentView.addView(view);
```

Comment: Yes, child view lost it's LayoutParams state.

Comment: But why you want to avoid creating layoutParams? Its Simple.

Comment: I know that it's easy) I asked, because may be someone has better solution)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add child to a RelativeLayout,you need to set LayoutParams for child view ,and if you want to add child to a LinerLayout,you don't need to set LayoutParams,so if you want to custom layoutParams,i suggest you to use RelativeLayout,or you can make a wrapper view for child View ,just like:

```
//inflate a wrapper view
View child = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
//add to a linerLayout
LinerLayout.addChild(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item, **container**, false);
layout.addView(view);
```